# jQuery sliding Menu with Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem creating a menu with jquery mouseenter / mouseout effects.
I want to have a small icon displayed and when the user hovers over the item it should expand to the left and show the menu link.

But it only works when you mouse over from down below but not from the side. its really weird behaviour.

Here is my css:

```
.userBlock {
       display: inline;
       float: right;
    }

    .userBlock a {
       padding-left: 15px;
       line-height: 35px;
       text-decoration: none;
       cursor: pointer;
       color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
       border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
       display: inline-block;
       font: bold 13px/36px "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
       width: 25px;
       overflow: hidden;
    }

    .userBlock a:last-child  {
       border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }

    .userBlock a span{
       margin-left: 15px;
    }
```

and my html:

```
 <div class="userBlock">
       <a>
           <img src="../images/config.ico" />
           <span>Test</span>
       </a>
       <!-- .... -->   
 </div>
```

finally my jquery:

```
// mouse over links
$('.userBlock a').mouseenter(
   function() {
      $(this).stop().delay(1).animate({'width':'100px'}, 500);
   }
);

// mouse leaves link
$('.userBlock a').mouseout(
   function() {
      $(this).stop().delay(1).animate({'width':'25px'}, 500);
   }
);
```

every help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **on**

```
// mouse over links
$(document).on('mouseenter', ".userBlock a", function() {
      $(this).stop().delay(1).animate({'width':'100px'}, 500);
   }
);

// mouse leaves link
$(document).on('mouseleave', ".userBlock a", function() {
      $(this).stop().delay(1).animate({'width':'25px'}, 500);
   }
);
```

**UPDATE**

[Updated JSFiddel Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BekNP/1/)

**Added `height:25px;` to `.userBlock a` in CSS**

Aligning the text and image is not done as this is not your question.

Comment: thank you ! Just quickly... how do i align text and image here ?

Comment: Small question, why the `.delay(1)`?

Comment: @arbitter Dont know. OP wants to delay it. See the script in original question. So I put here :)

Comment: this is just there to play with the delay. i decided against it eventually